# Is is possible to have my own tag attribute in the HTML code?

Tags: html

I know the input have the maxlength, but I would like to have minlength as my personal application for define, can I have this abilities? of course, the behavior is implemented by javascript, instead of the browser, can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

To make it validate with HTML5, prefix your custom attribute with `data-`.

You can get the `minlength` attribute in JavaScript with...

```
var minLength = +inputElement.getAttribute('data-minlength');
```

Comment: Exactly. As to why the `data-` prefix - if you don't use it, and one day minlength comes along, your site will break.

Comment: if the browser is not support HTML5, what will happen if I use the data-?

Comment: @TedWong Nothing will happen. It will still work. It just won't validate as anything but HTML5.